# Spark Task Data loss after worker dies in Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, beam

I have a Java program in which I use `Spark` as a runner for beam pipeline.
There is a `Spark` task that collects some data. It got finished correctly but, after that, its worker died and this task got assigned to another worker.
Why doesn't it recover the data that's already collected?
What's the best way to recover this data ?

I tried using `shuffle service` but still faced the same problem. Any advice is welcome.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.